# How do you find the top rated user for a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, top-users

I'm trying to find the top rated users for specific tags, but I am not sure if I can do this. I see https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month but want something like https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&tag=ruby (which obviously doesn't work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers

Just select a tag from the /questions or /tags pages and then click the "top users" link:

> [image: Ruby top users]

Comment: awesome thx, is there a way to get the past week? thx

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: @timpone You can always write a [data.se] query, [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/so/query/145948) may help.

Comment: thx Dukeling. I'll try that.